# set_alpha() for partially transparent surface

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to do this:

```
surface_with_text = pygame.font(params).render(params) # transparent bg
surface_with_text.set_alpha(100) # make it half transparent
another_surface.blit(surface_with_text) # blit onto image
```

But, of course, it silently fails - my text is still fully opaque... Why so? How do I find a workaround?

Of course I can blit "255 - 100"-transparent another_surface copy on the top of the text, but what fun is that, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rendered font surface is already using per-pixel alpha values (otherwise, it'd have a solid background).

From the [`Font.render` doc](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#Font.render):

> If the background is transparent a pixel alpha will be included.

From the [`set_alpha` doc](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.set_alpha):

> This value is different than the per pixel Surface alpha. If the Surface format contains per pixel alphas, then this alpha value will be ignored.

Comment: Yes, font surface is using per-pixel alpha values. Is there nothing I can do with it and my only option is blitting text onto copy of desired surface, make it half-transparent and blit the result to desired surface?

Comment: If you look in the comments for `set_alpha`, there are ways you can adjust the alpha of a surface without creating another surface.

Comment: Yup, noticed that comment - wanted to make sure there are no built -in methods I missed. Thank you!